# time executing inserts + slow SSH

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.1, performance, slow-log

_ Hello,

my setup is a slow SSH to some linux machine. From there I start a mysql terminal client and execute about 200k inserts (in a while loop inside a stored procedure). This takes about 3 hours to complete. However, my inner sense is telling me that 200k inserts can't take that long (the DB is empty btw), so I am guessing that DB's feedback (line prints to terminal's stdin file descriptor) gets printed onscreen too slow; first on the local terminal on the linux machine, and then even slower on my screen I am SSH-ing from.

I would surely like to turn off all feedback from mysqld so that I would know when the inserts finished only when the mysql's client prompt got back. Probably much sooner than 3 hours. How could I do that ?

/etc/my.cnf follows:

```
[mysqld]
datadir=/var/lib/mysql
socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
user=mysql
# Default to using old password format for compatibility with mysql 3.x
# clients (those using the mysqlclient10 compatibility package).
old_passwords=1

# Disabling symbolic-links is recommended to prevent assorted security risks;
# to do so, uncomment this line:
# symbolic-links=0

[mysqld_safe]
log-error=/var/log/mysqld.log
pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
```

follows the stored procedures:

```
    select 'Initializing database..';
call TigInitdb();

-- Possible encodings are:
-- - 'MD5-USERID-PASSWORD'
-- - 'MD5-PASSWORD'
-- - 'PLAIN'
-- More can be added if needed.
call TigPutDBProperty('password-encoding', 'PLAIN');
call TigPutDBProperty('schema-version', '4.0');

select 'Adding new users with PlainPw: ', '+391xxxxxx', 'pwd_xxxxxx';
drop function if exists TigUserGen;

delimiter //

create procedure TigAddUser(_user_id varchar(2049) CHARSET utf8, _user_pw varchar(255) CHARSET utf8)
begin
    declare res_uid bigint unsigned;

    insert into tig_users (user_id, sha1_user_id, user_pw)
        values (_user_id, sha1(lower(_user_id)), _user_pw);

    select LAST_INSERT_ID() into res_uid;

    insert into tig_nodes (parent_nid, uid, node)
        values (NULL, res_uid, 'root');

    if _user_pw is NULL then
        update tig_users set account_status = -1 where uid = res_uid;
    end if;

    select res_uid as uid;
end //

create procedure TigUserGen(usr_count INT)
begin
    DECLARE cnt,len INT;  
    DECLARE usr CHAR(6);  
    SET cnt = 0;
    SET len = 0;
    SET usr = '';  

    WHILE cnt < usr_count DO  
        SET cnt = cnt + 1;
        SET usr = CAST(cnt AS CHAR(6));
        SET len = CHAR_LENGTH(usr);
        CASE len
            WHEN 1 THEN 
                call TigTestAddUser(CONCAT('+39100000', usr), CONCAT('pwd_00000', usr), 'SUCCESS - adding new user', 'ERROR - adding new user');
            WHEN 2 THEN 
                call TigTestAddUser(CONCAT('+3910000', usr), CONCAT('pwd_0000', usr), 'SUCCESS - adding new user', 'ERROR - adding new user');
            WHEN 3 THEN 
                call TigTestAddUser(CONCAT('+391000', usr), CONCAT('pwd_000', usr), 'SUCCESS - adding new user', 'ERROR - adding new user');
            WHEN 4 THEN 
                call TigTestAddUser(CONCAT('+39100', usr), CONCAT('pwd_00', usr), 'SUCCESS - adding new user', 'ERROR - adding new user');
            WHEN 5 THEN 
                call TigTestAddUser(CONCAT('+3910', usr), CONCAT('pwd_0', usr), 'SUCCESS - adding new user', 'ERROR - adding new user');
            ELSE 
                call TigTestAddUser(CONCAT('+391', usr), CONCAT('pwd_', usr), 'SUCCESS - adding new user', 'ERROR - adding new user');
        END CASE;
    END WHILE;  
end //

delimiter ;

call TigUserGen(200000);
```

Thanks

Comment: Please post your my.cnf into the question

Comment: ok, I have now done so

Comment: Questions: 1) The stored procedure (SP) that does the 200K inserts, is it doing so one row at a time ? 2) Are you echoing from the SP after each insert ? 3) Can you post the SP in the question (of course hiding details of what is being inserted)?

Comment: ok, I have now done so (3). Regarding 1 and 2, I wouldn't know what to answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try commenting out the echoing of the uid

```
create procedure TigAddUser(_user_id varchar(2049) CHARSET utf8, _user_pw varchar(255) CHARSET utf8)
begin
    declare res_uid bigint unsigned;

    insert into tig_users (user_id, sha1_user_id, user_pw)
        values (_user_id, sha1(lower(_user_id)), _user_pw);

    select LAST_INSERT_ID() into res_uid;

    insert into tig_nodes (parent_nid, uid, node)
        values (NULL, res_uid, 'root');

    if _user_pw is NULL then
        update tig_users set account_status = -1 where uid = res_uid;
    end if;

    -- select res_uid as uid;
end //
```

Try throttling the output of the ids in groups of 1250

```
create procedure TigUserGen(usr_count INT)
begin
    DECLARE cnt,len,echo_count,echo_limit INT;  
    DECLARE usr CHAR(6);  
    SET cnt = 0;
    SET len = 0;
    SET usr = '';  

    SET echo_limit = 1250;    
    SET echo_count = 0;    
    WHILE cnt < usr_count DO  
        SET cnt = cnt + 1;
        SET echo_count = echo_count + 1;
        SET usr = CAST(cnt AS CHAR(6));
        SET len = CHAR_LENGTH(usr);
        CASE len
            WHEN 1 THEN 
                call TigTestAddUser(CONCAT('+39100000', usr), CONCAT('pwd_00000', usr), 'SUCCESS - adding new user', 'ERROR - adding new user');
            WHEN 2 THEN 
                call TigTestAddUser(CONCAT('+3910000', usr), CONCAT('pwd_0000', usr), 'SUCCESS - adding new user', 'ERROR - adding new user');
            WHEN 3 THEN 
                call TigTestAddUser(CONCAT('+391000', usr), CONCAT('pwd_000', usr), 'SUCCESS - adding new user', 'ERROR - adding new user');
            WHEN 4 THEN 
                call TigTestAddUser(CONCAT('+39100', usr), CONCAT('pwd_00', usr), 'SUCCESS - adding new user', 'ERROR - adding new user');
            WHEN 5 THEN 
                call TigTestAddUser(CONCAT('+3910', usr), CONCAT('pwd_0', usr), 'SUCCESS - adding new user', 'ERROR - adding new user');
            ELSE 
                call TigTestAddUser(CONCAT('+391', usr), CONCAT('pwd_', usr), 'SUCCESS - adding new user', 'ERROR - adding new user');
        END CASE;
        IF echo_count >= echo_limit THEN
            SELECT CONCAT('Users Generated : ',cnt) TigUserGenStatus;
            SET echo_count = 0;
        END IF;
    END WHILE;  
    IF echo_count >= 0 THEN
        SELECT CONCAT('Users Generated : ',cnt) TigUserGenStatus;
    END IF;
end //

delimiter ;

call TigUserGen(200000);
```

Comment: thanks. Will try tomorrow as my mysql is now in a deplorable state. Two versions on the same machine, unusable :|. Btw, the formatting of my code is now much nicer. How do you do it ? It never comes out that nicely when I select it and press the curly brackets icon.